# FullSimplify in term of some expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to simplify some expression in term of given expressions?

For example, `x = a + b`, `y = a - b` and `z = a^2 - b^2` (Clearly, `z = (a + b) (a - b) = x y`)

So I use `FullSimplify[z]` but I want to have `x y` as output.

How can I write a code for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`Simplify` or `FullSimplify` are not the best tool for this task, in my opinion. Try [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) instead, specifying which variables to eliminate in your system of equations:

```
Solve[{x == a + b, y == a - b, z == a^2 - b^2}, z, {a, b}]

(* Out: {{z -> x y}} *)
```

Note the use of `==` ([`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) and not `=` ([`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) to define equations.

Comment: Arhhhhhhhhh!!!! That is an brilliant idea.
Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: @kompaui I'm glad this helped! If you think that my answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the gray check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Eliminate[{z == a^2 - b^2, x == a + b, y == a - b}, {a, b}]
```

> `z==x*y`